# How to streamline this (rather large) MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**I thought I was pretty good at this sort of thing but...**

I have the following  query from a customer table that is about 8,500 rows and an address table that is about the same number of rows.

This query takes about ***10 seconds to complete*** and I can't figure how to get it to milliseconds.

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
<select>
<option value=""></option>
<?php // get the customers
    $sql = "
        SELECT `cust`.`custid`, `cust`.`custname`, `cust`.`custactive`, `address`.`addtype`, `address`.`address1`, `address`.`addcity`, `address`.`addstate`
        FROM `cust`
        LEFT Join `address` 
        ON `cust`.`custid` = `address`.`addcustid`
        and `address`.`addtype` = 'b'
        WHERE `cust`.`custactive` = 'y'"
    ;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Query failed: Could not get list of CLIENTS: ' . mysqli_error($con)); // query
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $custid = $row['custid'];
                $space="";
                $endingspaces = 4-(2*strlen($prodid));
                for($count=1; $count<$endingspaces; $count++){
                    $space .="&nbsp;";
                }

                $custid = $row['custid'];
                $custname = substr($row['custname'],0,15);
                $address1 = substr($row['address1'],0,15);
                $addcity = substr($row['addcity'],0,15);
                $addstate = $row['addstate'];

                print "<option value=\"$custid\">$custid: $space$custname, $address1, $addcity, $addstate</option>";                                                
        }
?>
</select>
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `cust` (
  `custid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custactive` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custcreated` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custmodified` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_dataease_custid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custtype` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custrep` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custsource` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custdiscount` decimal(65,30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custrepcomm` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custsurcharge` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custterms` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custups` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custnotes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custbilldif` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `custid` (`custid`),
  KEY `cust_dataease_custid_idx` (`cust_dataease_custid`),
  KEY `custrep_idx` (`custrep`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `addid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `addcustid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `addname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addtype` enum('b','s') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'b',
  `address1` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addcity` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addstate` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addstateother` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addzip` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addcountry` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addnote` tinyblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`addid`),
  KEY `add_cust_id_idx` (`addcustid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13037 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: zero. Never had to use them before.

Comment: 1. post output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE cust` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE address`. 2. rethink the calculation of $space (`str_repeat()`?)

Comment: Run `ALTER TABLE cust CREATE KEY custid(custid)` and `ALTER TABLE address CREATE KEY addcustid(addcustid), CREATE KEY addtype(addtype), CREATE KEY custactive(custactive)`

Comment: could it be "ADD KEY custid(custid);"?  i added keys, but as you can probably see, cust.custid adn address.addcustid are already keys.

Comment: @user3225456 That's your problem. Add indexes and you're query will go much faster.

Comment: never done that before. Is there a good tutorial on how to do it? I feel I added the above indexes and it has not sped anything up. What do you have to do with the database after you add keys? or will it work right afterwards?

Comment: Is the problem that your query is taking 10s, or that your browser has to render 8500 option elements?

Comment: The problem is that the browser is rendering 8500 option elements. I just did the query in mysql workbench and it only took 0.16 seconds, which is great. So I'm wondering how to speed this up because the php above throws all the option elements to one long string then to the browser, so how could I speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

**John Green** got me to thinking about the way information was being sent to and from the server, which led me to find the problem. Thanks John.

**This is how I fixed it:** Apparently, when my loop was iterating, it was "printing" each of the 8500 OPTION lines, which action (i didn't know), is a server-client interaction. So for each row, the server and browser had to have a conversation, which slowed everything down.

I fixed it by having the server compile the entire SELECT box on the server side, including the opening SELECT tags and interacting with the browser once through echoing my "add-to" variable: $select_box.

Now it takes like 1.2 seconds. I can live with that.

Thanks everyone for helping me chase this rabbit.

```
<?php // get the products
    $select_box = "<select name=\"customer\" id=\"customer\" onChange=\"getcustinfo();\" data-placeholder=\"Choose a Customer\" class=\"chosen-select\" style=\"width:227px;\" tabindex=\"1\">
<option value=\"\"></option>";

    $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM `cust`
        LEFT Join `address` 
        ON `cust`.`custid` = `address`.`addcustid`
        and `address`.`addtype` = 'b'
        WHERE `cust`.`custactive` = 'y'"
    ;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Query failed: Could not get list of CLIENTS: ' . mysqli_error($con)); // query
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                foreach ($row as $key => $value){ ${$key} = $value; }
                $space="";   
                $custname = substr($row['custname'],0,15);
                $address1 = substr($row['address1'],0,15);
                $addcity = substr($row['addcity'],0,15);

                $select_box .= "<option value=\"$custid\">$custid: $space$custname, $address1, $addcity, $addstate</option>";                                               
        }
    $select_box .="</select>";
    echo $select_box;   
?>
```